# Get node based target id from entity reference

Tags: 8, nodes, database, hooks

We have an `Article` content type which has an Entity Reference field called `field_document` that is linked to the `Media` bundle type of `Document`. In `mymodule` we need to write a hook that will take the current `field_document.id` (which maps to `Document.mid`) and return all the `Article` pages where `field_document.target_id = mid`.

**Goal**

- Take the current node id and retrieve the `Document` entity that is linked to by accessing `field_document`
- Using the `field_document` value, return other `Articles` that have the same value for `field_document`
- Perform the query in a `hook_preprocess_node()` hook.

**Question**

1. How can we retrieve all the nodes based on the $mid?

**When we tried**

We were able to return all `Articles`. However when we add `->condition('field_document.target_id, $mid)`, we get zero results even though we know there are `Articles` where the `field_document.target_id = $mid`.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $linked_document_id = $node->get('field_document')->first()->getValue()['target_id'];

  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = $node_storage->getQuery()
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->condition('status', 1);

  $and = $query->andConditionGroup();
  $and->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');
  $query->condition($and);
  $results = $query->execute();

  // returns zero
  ksm($results);
}
```

We also tried using `$and->condition('field_document.target_id', $linked_document_id, '=');`, but that did not return any results either.

Additional steps we tried, but with similar issue.

```
 function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $linked_document_id = $node->get('field_document')->first()->getValue()['target_id'];

  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = $node_storage->getQuery()
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->condition('status', 1);
    ->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');
  $results = $query->execute();

  // returns zero
  ksm($results);
}
```

Comment: Although I don't think it would affect your result, is there a reason why you are creating an andConditionGroup() instead of just appending your condition onto the other conditions? Conditions by default are 'AND', and since your group only has as single condition, it doesn't appear to be grouping anything.

Comment: @Jaypan We only used the `andConditionGroup()` to see if we got separate results, but that did not happen.

Comment: Have you checked that `$linked_document_id` contains the value you think it should?

Comment: @Jaypan `field_document` is required and will always have a value. I tried using a bunch of kint statements as well. for some reason the `->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');` just returns `zero` results

Comment: Again though, are you sure $linked_document_id contains the value you  think it does? Have you done kint() on that variable?

Comment: the second code works for me, but i think the is `;` in it shouldn't be after `->condition('status', 1);` try with `  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = $node_storage->getQuery()
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');
  $results = $query->execute();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue, it was both duplicate data issue and syntax errors mentioned by @berramou. The fix to the query was  changing `->condition('status', 1);` line to `->condition('status', 1)`.

We found that the test data included duplicate `media` entities so when the `->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');` was added, there were no results because the `entities` we were expecting were not in the table.

Sample test data:

- media entity (id=1) name --> foo
- media entity (id=2) name --> foo
- media entity (id=3) name --> bar
- Article->field_document->target_id = 1

I was expecting `foo (id=1)` to be returned but I was receiving `foo (id=2)`. We have a specific requirement that `media entities` should be unique so after we merged the duplicate ones, the issue resolved.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node($variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $linked_document_id = $node->get('field_document')->first()->getValue()['target_id'];

  $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
  $query = $node_storage->getQuery()
    ->condition('type', 'article')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('field_document', $linked_document_id, '=');
  $results = $query->execute();

  // returns results now
  ksm($results);
}
```